# how to determine the URL for ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

As stated in the title...I am having trouble determining whether I'm actually performing the post operation properly or if the operation is properly performed then why is the value empty since I checked the value before passing it in the post operation...here is my code:

script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/Index/viewDayDocuments",
    type: 'post',
    data: {currentDay: 'currentDay', currentMonth: 'currentMonth', currentYear: 'currentYear'},
    success: function(result){
        $('.list').text('');
        $('.list').remove();
        $(".listIncoming").html("<p class = 'list'>This is the: "+ result +"</p>");
        $("#myform").show(500);
    }
 });
```

controller code which throws back a return value:

```
    $data['day'] = $_POST['currentDay'];
        $data['month'] =  $_POST['currentMonth'];
        $data['year'] =  $_POST['currentYear'];

        $date = $data['year']."-".$data['month']."-".$data['day'];

        $this->load->model('search_form');
        $output['details'] = $this->search_form->searchDateRetrievedIncoming($date);

        return $data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request needs a string echoed as a string.

```
  $data['day'] = $_POST['currentDay'];
    $data['month'] =  $_POST['currentMonth'];
    $data['year'] =  $_POST['currentYear'];

    $date = $data['year']."-".$data['month']."-".$data['day'];

    $this->load->model('search_form');
    $output['details'] = $this->search_form->searchDateRetrievedIncoming($date);

    echo json_encode($data);
```

An array cannot be echoed out correctly if it's not in a data format, such as JSON.

Now we, take the data in your javascript

```
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/Index/viewDayDocuments",
type: 'post',
data: {currentDay: 'currentDay', currentMonth: 'currentMonth', currentYear: 'currentYear'},
success: function(result){
    $('.list').text('');
    $('.list').remove();
    date = JSON.parse(result);
    $(".listIncoming").html("<p class = 'list'>This is the: "+ date.month +"/"+date.day+ "/"+date.year +"</p>");
    $("#myform").show(500);
  } 
 });
```

In this module, I transformed the STRING from your PHP file into a JSON object so it can be read properly.

Comment: I tried your suggestion nothing seems to be happening though I think...do you think it may be the URL after all??

Comment: ok it really is a URL problem...don't know why though but I changed the URL from this: "<?php echo base_url();?>/Index/viewDayDocuments" to this: "viewDayDocuments"

Comment: Oh I forgot to tell you. It is not advisable to echo base_url() or any other function to scripts. You should use $.ajaxPrefilter() instead, from JQuery. So that you only have to change one URL parameter if you port to a different server.